# The rank of cross-covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, matrix

Let $\boldsymbol{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_p)^T$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}=(Y_1,\dots,Y_q)^T$ be two random vectors. Denote $r_x=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X})),r_y=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol{Y})), r_{(x,y)}=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{Cov}([\boldsymbol{X}^T,\boldsymbol{Y}^T]^T))$, and $r_{xy}=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y}))$, where $\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y})=[\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)]_{p\times q}$.

Given $r_x,r_y,r_{(x,y)}$,
can $r_{xy}$ be represented by a formula of $r_x,r_y,r_{(x,y)}$?

If not, is it correct that $r_{xy}\ge r_x+r_y-r_{(x,y)}$?

Comment: Writing \operatorname{Cov} instead of \text{Cov} gives you proper spacing in things like $A\operatorname{Cov} B$ and $A\operatorname{Cov}(B).$ I edited accordingly. $\qquad$